# implement undo tasks mechanism in airflow

Tags: airflow, mwaa

I need to implement some kind of rollback mechanism in a DAG. There are three tasks, and the first two tasks have each of them an undo task. What I would need to do is the following:

task1 >> task2 >> task3

if task3 fails, I need to undo the two previous tasks in the following order:
undo_task2 >> undo_task1

and if case the task2 fails, then I'll only need to undo the task1.

I have been reading about branch operators on airflow, but I wouldn't really know how to implement it for my use case, or if there would be a better solution.

Thanks!

Comment: what mean `undo`? Do you need just restart whole `pipeline` / `tasks`?

Comment: no, I wanted to trigger new tasks which would undo the tasks run before.

Comment: ok. So do you need behavior the same as [airflow tasks clear -d](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#clear)?